# linear combination of two factors of minimal polynomial is $1$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, polynomials, minimal-polynomials

> Let $K$ be a field and $V$ a finite dimensional $K$-vector space. Let
> $A$ be a linear transformation of $V$ with minimal polynomial
> $\phi_A$. Let $\phi_A = \phi_1 \cdot \phi_2$ with $\phi_1, \phi_2 \in K[X]$ monic and relative prime.
>
> There exist polynomials $g,h \in K[X]$ so that $g \phi_1 + h \phi_2 = 1$.

I do not see the logic behind this? Why is this the case? I suppose it is because the product of $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ is the minimal polynomial for $A$, but I do not see entirely why.

Comment: This is simply Bézout's identity https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_greatest_common_divisor#B%C3%A9zout's_identity_and_extended_GCD_algorithm

Comment: This particular fact (makes no reference to $V$ and therefore) has no relation to $\phi_A$ being a minimal polynomial and the product of $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$; it holds for any pair of relatively prime polynomials whatsoever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*As you tagged abstract-algebra I hope the following is understandable to you. Otherwise feel free to ask for clarification!*

In a principal ideal domain $R$ elements $a,b\in R$ are relatively prime, iff their gcd is 1. As ideals we have the identity $(a)+(b)=(\gcd(a,b))$. This is equivalent to the condition that $\gcd(a,b)$ is a unit, wlog 1. By definition of $(a)+(b)$ we thus have $ka + lb = 1$ for some $k,l \in R$.

If $K$ is a field then $K[X]$ is a principal ideal domain. So having polynomials $\phi_1,\phi_2$ being relatively prime, we find polynomials $g,h$ such that $g\phi_1 + h\phi_2=1$.